# Windows 7 and 10. Low on memory error

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, memory, ssd

I have a laptop of about 8 years old. Recently I have changed its hard drive for a new SSD. After that, I installed Windows 7 because there is a notion that it would be faster if you have Win 7 instead of Win 10. After a short time, I started to receive a "Low on memory" error. When such error pops up all applications stop responding to any of my actions, but for example, video can continue playing.

[Low on memory error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQ3s6.jpg)

I have browsed some solutions and most of them suggest changing virtual memory. I have tried different combinations of min virtual memory and max virtual memory but I still had been keeping to receive this error. After some time I have switched to Win 10 again, hoping that might be the problem. The error doesn't pop up but with the same frequency, all applications just stop responding, even windows explorer. So I think the problem is still present. Any tips?

[Here is my configuration.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9rzv.jpg)

[Current virtual memory set up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsZTr.jpg)

Comment: If you're comfortable changing OS, try a Linux distro such as Ubuntu, http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/ , since Linux requires far fewer resources than Windows now does. You can run it from a USB flash drive without even having to install it.

Comment: The thing is, it is my mother's laptop, so she will have a difficult times adapting to the new OS. She always used Windows.

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't the answer you're looking for but that 8 year old laptop is almost definitely just not capable of running current programs smoothly. While the minimum requirements for Windows 10 lists 2GB of RAM, anything less than 4GB will start to have these exact issues, and your Pentium processor was only entry level when it was released almost 10 years ago so it is incredibly underpowered now. You would be best off buying a used laptop anywhere in the last 5 years or so and using the new SSD in that.

That said, you could try setting the virtual memory to custom at 4, 6, or even 8GB if your SSD has the space (4096, 6144, or 8192MB) which might help some if the Pentium can transfer from the SSD smoothly enough. If you can find compatible RAM online adding another stick would obviously help too and probably wouldn't be too expensive.

Comment: Unfortunately, at this point I think that new SSD is worth more than that entire computer.

Comment: SSD 256 GB cost me just 50 dollars. The thing is, this laptop didn't have any problems running Win 10 with old HDD. It was slow but there weren't any memory errors. So I see that CPU is responsible for transferring virtual memory if RAM is not enough? Could it be that this SSD is too much for this CPU?

Comment: In theory that's possible but it would be pretty unlikely. Is there any chance the original copy of Win 10 on the old hard drive was 32 bit? I noticed under system type you currently have 64 bit which will run worse in low-memory situations. (ex. recommended RAM for 32 bit windows is 1GB while it's 2GB for 64 bit)
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028142/windows-windows-10-system-requirements

Comment: @LostWander Before SSD upgrade it was also 64 bit. I was wondering. I also use some fan system for external cooling. It is placed under the laptop and connected to it by USB on both sides. Could it case some malfunction?

Comment: That would be another unlikely one unfortunately. For cooling you're best bet is to use some compressed air to blow out the dust from the internal fans. Another issue that could be causing problems is the thermal paste on the processor degrading and reducing cooling no matter how much external cooling you add. 

This is really sounding a lot like a money pit so I can't recommend enough just saving up for a slightly newer used laptop instead. Even Chromebooks are decently user friendly these days if your mom is just looking to do basic things like typing or watching videos.